# Pandas dataframe search and modify leading zero on postal codes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, leading-zero

I have a pandas DataFrame database of location and postal code addresses. But postal codes have been interpreted from Excel reading. For example, in France postal addresses are a department code followed by city code, e.g. 75600 (75 = 'Paris region', 600 = 'inner city').

But in some first postal codes, e.g. 01200 it have interpreted like 1200. How can I search integer values below 10000 and modify them? Or how to preserve the first zero. How to search and replace in a dataframe and use the content (to modify it)?

Comment: '01200' is not an integer, it's a string; so one option is to store address codes as strings. Alternative is to print/format/represent integers as 'f'{n:05d}''. **It depends do you want to store match or merely the optional output leading zeros?** You have to **edit the question to tell us.** So far there's nothing pandas-specific here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as I understood, one possible solution is to preserve the firs 0 when postal code < 10000. Is that it? One way is to convert all entries to string.

```
import pandas as pd
# example with only two locations in column 0 of a DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame([75600, 1200])
# convert all entries in column 0 to string, adding '0' to the beginning when postal code < 10000
df = df[0].apply(lambda x: '0' + str(x) if x < 10000 else str(x))
```

If this is not the solution you want please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution to the problem could be using the built in `zfill` option that Pandas provides to Strings.

```
df[0] = df[0].apply(lambda x : str(x).zfill(5))
```

Here `zfill` with the parameter of `5` is saying that the string must be at least 5 places. If the string does not fulfill this there are leading zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Solution of df = df[0].apply(lambda x: '0' + str(x) if x < 10000 else str(x)) is perfect. It convert the code to full string and then I can find GPS coordinates correspondant to national postal infos.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest creating a new column instead of attempting to replace on the fly.

Something like this...

E.g.,

```
In [42]: df=pd.DataFrame([{"Location": "some_loc", "Code": "75600"}, {"Location": "some_other_loc", "Code": "01200"}, {"Location": "another_loc", "Code": "08100"}])

In [43]: df
Out[43]:
         Location   Code
0        some_loc  75600
1  some_other_loc  01200
2     another_loc  08100

In [46]: df["NewCode"] = [str(int(x)) if int(x) < 10000 else None for x in df["Code"]]

In [47]: df
Out[47]:
         Location   Code NewCode
0        some_loc  75600    None
1  some_other_loc  01200    1200
2     another_loc  08100    8100
```